# TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatAMPM' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I am importing a module (called activity.js) to be tested. This module(activity.js) imports formatAMPM using:
`import {formatAMPM} from '../config/helper` -> activity.js

I updated from react-native 0.55.4 to 0.58.6 using `https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.55.4&to=0.58.6`, and maybe this caused the problem. But I am not sure.

activity.js

```
import {
    SET_ACTIVITY_DATE,
    SET_ACTIVITY_START_TIME,
    SET_ACTIVITY_DURATION,
    SET_ACTIVITY_SRC,
    SET_ACTIVITY_DEST,
    SET_ACTIVITY_TYPE,
    SET_ACTIVITY_DISTANCE,
    SET_ACTIVITY_CO2
} from '../actions/ActivityDetailsAction';
import { formatAMPM } from '../config/helper';

export default function activity(
    state = {
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
        startTime: formatAMPM(new Date()),
        duration: 0,
        src: { latitude: -1, longitude: -1 },
        dest: { latitude: -1, longitude: -1 },
        type: 'STILL',
        distance: 0,
        co2: 0
    },
    action
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ACTIVITY_DATE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                date: action.value
            });
            ...
```

helper.js

```
/**
 * helper function to format date
 * @param  Date date
 * @return {time} formatted time
 */
export function formatAMPM(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return time;
}
```

When I run `npm run test`, this error message shows in terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatAMPM' of undefined

      33 |     },
      34 |     action
    > 35 | ) {
      36 |     switch (action.type) {
      37 |         case SET_ACTIVITY_DATE:
      38 |             return Object.assign({}, state, {
```

Comment: make sure the import path is right

Comment: Trust me, I've checked that like a million times (a little exagerated maybe).